# Android API for sampling download and upload speed

Tags: java, android, profiling, android-download-manager, speed-test

This is not really a programming question right now, and is more like a start point. I'm trying to write an Android app to take samples every few seconds and profile download and upload speed, plus some more information such as time stamp, longitude and latitude given from GPS, and save all as a .csv file when done.

I was wondering if there are any APIs, libraries, or a project somewhere I could use as a start point? Any hints?

I've found a [ConnectionClass](https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class), but I'm not sure if it gives enough flexibility to do that.

Comment: try my library https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking

Comment: Interesting! But I couldn't find anything about profiling and speed test. Do you have any pointer to those, maybe some examples?

Comment: There is no built in Android library because testing the speed requires server component (you need to specify which server the content will be downloaded/uploaded to measure its speed).

There are many sampling methodologies , there is no one "true" speed. 


You can also use our Android SDK which should do what you need and is compliant with ITU standard>
https://github.com/speedchecker/speedchecker-sdk-android

Comment: You can also check following standards:
https://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/C-I/Pages/IM/Internet-speed.aspx

https://www.itu.int/itu-t/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=q.3960

https://www.itu.int/ITU-T/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=14125

https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc6349.pdf